# Snow Leopard and SonicWall NetExtender VPN?

Tags: vpn, osx-snow-leopard

I recently upgraded from Leopard to Snow Leopard, and now I'm having strange issues with a previously working NetExtender.

After debugging a "can't read/execute `/etc/ppp/peers`" problem (since `/etc/ppp` didn't exist) and following the [advice on the Apple support forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10119060) (I tried a clean install, and `sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pppd` had no effect), I'm getting this error:

```
Connected.
Logging in...
Login successful.
Using SSL Encryption Cipher 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'
Using new PPP frame encoding mechanism
SSL-VPN logging out...
FATAL: An error was detected in processing the options given, such as two mutually exclusive options being used. (2)
SSL-VPN connection is terminated.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the newest update to the netextender its like 3.5 something this will fix connection issues with 10.6.1

Comment: That is the proper answer, but when I posted the question, the most recent version of NetExtender was still broken.